# Can marijuana help treat Crohn's Disease?

Tags: inflammation, marijuana, crohns, appetite, ulcerative-colitis

I was recently talking to a friend about my Crohns and he said he heard that marijuana can help treat it. 
When I was first diagnosed, I decided NOT to go on medicine and have therefore been on the Specific Carbohydrate Diet. It works for me, but it is extremely restrictive and difficult to live with.

Are there any studies or tests that show that having a "brownie" once a day can be helpful in treating Crohns?

*I have searched Google, but I find the entire issue of marijuana extremely biased one way or the other. Either its the miracle drug that cures all and let me walk on water and turn it into wine (or at least think I am), or its the worst plant ever discovered.*

Comment: I've never heard of MJ helping Crohn's, but maybe it just makes you feel better about having the illness.  Have you tried kefir?  I've heard it is extremely helpful with all sorts of intestinal issues.  Worked wonders for my IBS.